# C++ dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, virtual, dynamic-cast

```
class A
{
};

class B:public A
{
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    A *ap = &b;
    B *bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap);
    if(bp!= NULL)
       cout<<"Pass"<<endl;
    else
       cout<<"Fail"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why should class A be virtual if you want to do a dynamic cast?

Answer (score 7):

`dynamic_cast` works differently from `static_cast`. The results of a `static_cast` are always a pointer. However, if the cast is incorrect (to a type that the given pointer wasn't originally), then the result of the cast is undefined; the pointer is not necessarily valid. Thus, there is some degree of uncertainty when casting to derived classes with `static_cast`; there is no mechanism to prevent you from casting to the wrong things.

`dynamic_cast` will return either a valid pointer if the cast is correct, or a null pointer if it is incorrect. Thus, the results are well-defined in all cases. In order to do this, `dynamic_cast` must be *dynamic*. This means that it has to do runtime checks on the pointer to see if the type being cast to is a legal cast operation.

C++ forbids casts for non-virtual types due to the "pay for what you use" principle: a type that doesn't have virtual functions is generally not a type that you're passing around by its base classes. Inheritance without virtuals is primarily about using the existing implementation, not about specializing functions. Even something as simple as a virtual destructor is sufficient.

The machinery needed to do `dynamic_cast` is non-zero. So, under the "pay for what you use" principle, only those classes where it would be *useful* pay for them. IE: those classes which are virtual.

Answer (score 1):

The output will be something along the lines:

> Error xxxx: invalid parameter to `dynamic_cast`. Class is of non-polymorphic type.

The classes need to be polymorphic because that's the specification for `dynamic_cast`. Internally, `dynamic_cast` checks virtual table pointers, but that's an implementation detail.

You can use `static_cast` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`virtual` is the key of polymorphysm. A virtual function means it is "overriddenable" by a derived class, otherwise there is no polymorphysm between the classes, there is just inheritance. If the classes are not polymorphic, the `dynamic_cast` cannot be used.